# "I don't know that I can" vs "I don't know if I can"

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning in the following sentences.

> The teacher told me that I would pass the test, but I don't know **that** I can.
>
> The teacher told me that I would pass the test, but I don't know **if** I can.

Comment: Did you intend to emphasize the second occurrence of the word **that** in the first sentence?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake

Comment: There isn't really any difference in meaning. Both sentences say that you are not sure whether or not you can pass the test. We tend to use *that* when we are talking about something that has been taken to be true in the background. It cold be something that the person you are speaking to has said, or something that you would normally expect to be true. For example, if you are buying something and the assistant says *I'll check [that] we have it in stock*, this implies he thinks they do have it in stock, whereas *I'll check if we have it in stock* wouldn't imply anything...

Comment: in your sentence (by the way it should be *my teacher told ME that...* or *my teacher said that...*) you are saying that you don't know, so the reason for using *that* could only be to refer to the fact that it has been said... but since you've just said it yourself, this doesn't add or change anything, and the meaning is just the same as with *if*.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a bit confused. Doesn't it mean that some is unsure if they check it? Could you please eleborate on the explabation with the word "check" and "that". And by the way, your comment would make a good answer.